# Is there a recurrence relation which has no closed formula?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

From what I know, it is unknown whether $x_n=x_{n-1}^2 + 1$ has a closed form. Is there a recurrence relation which is known to have no closed form with a proof of inexistence?

Assuming a closed form is a non recursive description using the elementary operations of addition multiplication and power, or, assuming any other good definition of "closed form".

**Edit**

There are similar questions out there, but the answers are a little bit going around the question.

So is there one with proof or is it unknown? And if it depends on the definition of a closed form, then what are the (or some) options? How strong can a closed form definition be to still have a recursive relation that can be proved to not being able to have its form?

Update

Because it is a big question, and I don't want to open a new small one, I think a good representative small question about this subject is: 
Is there a recurrence relation with a domain of the natural numbers, described by elementary functions, which has no closed form defined as:

A closed form of a recurrence relation with a domain of natural numbers is a function $f$ that can be described as a composition of a constant number of elementary functions without reccursion. i.e, $f(n) = f_1(f_2( \dots (f_k(n))) \dots) $ where $f_i$ is elementary for all $1 \leq i \leq k$

I think this definition is the most intuitive and basic.

For example, the relation $x_n = x_{n-1}+1$ has a closed form in this sense: $$f(n) = f_1(f_2(f_3(f_4(n))))$$

Where $f_1$ is division, $f_2(n)=(n,2)$, $f_3$ is multiplication and $f_4(n) = (n,n+1)$

Is there a recurrence relation which has no closed form in this sense?

Comment: This example is a good candidate for an example without a closed form, but I am not aware of a proof either.

Comment: Take a look at https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27598/recurrence-relations-that-do-not-have-a-closed-form-solution

Comment: Fix a language for closed forms, each a finite string in a countable alphabet. There are countably many forms, so enumerate them. In the spirit of [Richard's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard%27s_paradox), define $a_n$ as the $n$th form's $n$th term $+1$. Clearly, $a_n$ is none of the original forms, but it *looks* like I've defined it as one. This can be resolved if you know about metalanguages, but the moral is we need to formalise what a closed form is, or at least which notation is legal in it, to properly consider some questions. I wonder whether your question is one of them.

Comment: Much of the difficulty here depends on formalizing what a closed form is. I'm not aware of a generally accepted definition. In practice it turns out that closed forms aren't as big a deal as you might think.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure whether I get you correctly. There is a powerseries for the "Schroeder-function" associtated to $f(x)=1+x^2$ such that we can use it (and its inverse) to compute iterates by iteration-height $h$ as argument. This can -for a given iteration-initialization-value $x_0$ be made in a single power-series for $h$ as argument. Don't know, whether one would call such a powerseres a closed form, after $\exp(x)$ is also computable by a power series and yet is assumed to be a "closed-form".

Comment: After your clarifying edit: One could write the $h$'th -iteration of $f(x)=1+x^2$ as $f^{\circ h}(x)$ and then define $g(h)=f^{\circ h}(1)$ as the function in your question and ask, whether there is "*a closed form*" for $g(h)$. Here $g(h)$ would be the representative for your "*recursion*"-property. My previous comment refers to such a formulation in principle for the general type of conversion of some $f^{\circ h}(x)$ into $g(h)$ (here for your specific example of course). The $g(h)$ -notation is perhaps a clearer formalization for the recursion-idea in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a remark I put in a paper [1, p. 5828] of mine, which I got from an anonymous referee of that paper:

> We may resonably interpret "having closed form" as "being differentiably algebraic".  According to Eremenko, the integer iterates of a polynomial $M(x)$ are uniformly differentiably algebraic (= satisfy the same algebraic differential equation with constant coefficients) iff $M$ is conjugate (by a linear function) to a monomial, a Chebyshev polynomial, or the negative of a Chebyshev polynomial.  See  [2, p. 663].  In case $M(x) = x^2+c$, this means precisely $c=0$ or $c=-2$.

So in the case $M(x) = x^2+1$ mentioned by the O.P., the iteration does not have closed form in this sense.

**Note that Erimenko is a member here, so he may able to provide more information!**

[1] *Edgar, G. A.*, [**Fractional iteration of series and transseries**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-2013-05784-4), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 365, No. 11, 5805-5832 (2013). [ZBL1283.30001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1283.30001).

[2] *Rubel, Lee A.*, Some research problems about algebraic differential equations. II, Ill. J. Math. 36, No. 4, 659-680 (1992). [ZBL0768.34003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0768.34003).

Answer (score 5):

This may be kind of  weak, but in a certain sense, Liouville's theorem guarantees there is no closed formula for $a_0 =0$ and $a_n =  a_{n-1} + \int_{n-1}^n e^{-x^2} \text{d}x$.

Comment: No closed formula with only elementary functions. Certainly a closed formula using erf.

Comment: And that's an important point in many ways. Closed is something like ill definited

Comment: I think the question would be better phrased along the lines of "is there a *closed form* recurrence which has no closed form solution?". Your solution won't classify then, since you can't express $\int_{n-1}^n e^{-x^2}dx$ in closed form (without special functions).

Comment: Right. It's kind of weak, doubtless