# Is there a method for deriving a function given a system of equations containing references to said function?

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations, computer-science

For example, there's the archetypical Fibonacci sequence, which can be defined as

$$
\begin{align}
F(0) &= 0\\
F(1) &= 1\\
F(n) &= F(n-1) + F(n-2).
\end{align}
$$

The only continuous function *F* that satisfies the above system of equations is, as we probably all know,

$$
F(n) = \frac{\varphi^n - \psi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}},
$$

where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio and $\psi=-\varphi^{-1}$. This solution even holds for negative values of *n*.

My question is this: is there a method for deriving a continuous function only given a valid set of equations referencing said function? Or alternatively the set of functions satisfying a system of equations?

I suspect the answer is yes, since functional declarative programming languages like Haskell can say things such as

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

However, Haskell is able to do this in a generalised way for almost any valid function defined naïvely in this form. How exactly it achieves this eludes me, however.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. What do you mean by "continuous"? It looks like you're still defining $F$ on the integers. Perhaps you're looking for a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for recursively defined functions? As it stands, I don't fully understand what you're asking.

Comment: It's worth noting that your haskell code will run _extremely_ slowly (in fact, exponentially slowly) because in the process of computing $F(n)$, it computes (multiple times!) all of the $F(k)$ for $k < n$. So I'm not sure how it's any more of a "continuous function" than your original recursive definition.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4205834/how-to-solve-linear-recurrence-relations-with-constant-coefficients

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Hm, the third equation technically still holds for all real (and complex) numbers, but I can see how you can never get to a complex result only given $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$, so yeah you can ignore that part.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Also I wasn't aware of that fact about Haskell, I had been led to believe that the extreme recursion can be optimised away by the compiler with the right flags somehow.

Comment: @zwim Interesting, this seems to be what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: So are you asking when we can extend a function $F : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ (defined recursively) to a continuous function $\tilde{F} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? If you only want continuous, this is always true -- we can just linearly interpolate between the known integer values. Even if you want more, [smooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness) for instance, we can _still_ do it, we just need to be slightly smarter with how we interpolate. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606233/extending-functions-from-integers-to-reals-in-a-nice-way) for instance.

Comment: From your response to @zwim, it looks like you're trying to solve recurrences. One standard technique (which is very flexible) is via [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function). You can read more about solving recurrences with this technique in the (excellent) book generatingfunctionology, available for free [here](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html). You should be warned, though. In general it's not possible to find nice closed forms for recurrences. Even something as simple as $F(n) = F(n-1)^2 + 1$ doesn't have a closed form, as far as we know.

Comment: Well, not exactly (and I believe the type of the recursively defined function is $\mathbb Z \to\mathbb Z$, and the type of the actual continuous function can be said to be $\mathbb C \to\mathbb C$) I think I'm just extremely bad at formulating myself as I don't have a formal background in mathematics, haha. I guess what I meant to ask, in computer scientific terms, is just "is there a generalised algorithm that spits out a function given a set of constraints on that function?"

Comment: Then I'm afraid the answer is "no" as soon as the constraints become complicated in any reasonable sense. If you restrict attention to [linear recurrences](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/) then the answer is "yes", and in fact this has been done. See [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) for documentation on a very flexible recurrence solver that works in many cases. Unfortunately, it's still [totally open](https://mathoverflow.net/q/223422/145247) to compute even _asymptotics_ for general recurrences!

Comment: In the worst case, this problem is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) in the formal sense. Indeed, John Conway showed that _any computer program_ can be coded up as a "function with constraints" analogous to the [collatz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), see [fractran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FRACTRAN) for more.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Is this open even in the case of polynomial recurrences with real coefficients ? Since it seems that the author has such recurrences in mind , not collatz-like recurrences.

Comment: I have also an example in my answers of a relation defined on integers which is then extended to the reals by density and continuity --> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4278239/generalized-mergesort-time-complexity-functional-equation-fn-2f-left-fracn/4278301#4278301

Comment: @Peter -- the undecidability result is only for collatz like sequences, but I included it "in the worst case" because I still don't really understand how general a class of problems OP wants to solve. That said, as far as I know it's still open to find asymptotics for recurrences with polynomial coefficients. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223422/recurrence-relations-with-polynomial-coefficients-an-undecidable-problem)

Comment: @HallaSurvivor thank you very much for the concise answer and provided resources! I'd give you a tick mark if I could.

Comment: I'll make my response an answer, then ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

I think some of the confusion regarding the responses to this question come from the (admittedly subtle) distinction between a *closed form solution* to a recurrence and an *extension* of a recurrence (to all of $\mathbb{C}$, say).

If you're able to solve a recurrence, so that $T(n) = f(n)$ where $f$ is some "nice" function, then we get a canonical extension of $T$ to the whole of $\mathbb{C}$ (or whatever the domain of $f$ is) which is likely to be continuous (indeed, differentiable, smooth, analytic, etc.).

However, this is far from the *only* way to extend a recurrence to all of $\mathbb{C}$. As Somos points out, there are lots of functions $f$ so that $f(n) = T(n)$ on $\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, as you can see in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606233/extending-functions-from-integers-to-reals-in-a-nice-way), we can *always* find such an $f$. Though this is likely to be unsatisfying, since the $f$ we get seems to have nothing at all to do with our original recurrence! Moreover, the $f$ we get is likely to be difficult to compute with in practice.

So then, it seems like you're interested in *solving recurrences* (in the sense of finding a closed form), since this gives us a *canonical* means of extending the domain of $T$ which has the extra benefit of being "effective", in the sense that a good computer algebra system (like [sage](https://sagemath.org)) will be able to actually compute with the resulting function.

The good news is that there's *lots* of literature on solving recurrences. See, for instance, the excellent books *Generatingfunctionology* (freely and legally available [here](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/gfology2.pdf)) and *Concrete Mathematics* (freely and probably illegally available [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)).

The bad news is that solving recurrence relations is extremely difficult in general. Already the recurrence $T(n) = T(n-1)^2 + 1$ doesn't have a known closed form (and *provably* doesn't have a closed form for a certain formalization of that phrase. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3364729/is-there-a-recurrence-relation-which-has-no-closed-formula?noredirect=1)). Oftentimes it's a difficult problem to just obtain asymptotics for $T(n)$.

As an aside, recurrences are closely related to iterating polynomials. For instance, the recurrence relation above $T(n) = T(n-1)^2 + 1$ clearly satisfies $T(n) = \underbrace{p(p(p( \cdots (p}_{n \text{ times}}(T(0)) \cdots )))$, where $p(x) = x^2 + 1$, but at this point we should be quite worried! After all, iterating polynomials quickly gives rise to [chaotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) behavior. See the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) for a strikingly simple example. This gives some justification for why solving recurrences *must* be hard in general!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You claim that

> The only continuous function *F* that satisfies the above system of equations is, as we probably all know,
> $$
> F(n) = \frac{\varphi^n - \psi^{n}}{\sqrt{5}},
> $$

This claim in false even if $\,F\,$ is restricted
to real functions. Given any integer $\,k,\,$
define the confinuous complex function
$$ F_k(x) := e^{2\pi i k x}\frac{\varphi^x - \psi^{x}}{\sqrt{5}}. $$
It is easy to verify that it satisfies the
initial conditions $\, F_k(0) = 0, \;\;
F_k(1) = 1\,$ and the recursion
$$ F_k(x) = F_k(x-1) + F_k(x-2). $$
The **real** part of $\,F_k(x)\,$ also satisfies
the above conditions.

In general, given **any real** continuous function $\,f(x)\,$ defined on the
interval $\,[0,2)\,$ with $\,f(0)=0,\,$
and $\,f(1)=1,\,$ then it can be uniquely extended to the entire real line to also satisfy the recursion equation. Note that **all** of these
continuous functions $\,f(x)\,$  agree at **all** integer values of $\,x.\,$ That is, $\,f(n) =
F(n)\,$ for all integer $\,n.$

Comment: I'll be damned, you're completely right. I already got the answer to my actual question in the comments (it's "no"), but thanks for showing that the recursive Fibonacci definition can satisfy a lot more than just one equation over a complex domain.